# Unit test Factory class in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, rhino-mocks

I have third party api wrapper class that need to authenticate using user name password so I have put initialization setup in Factory class like

```
public class ApiClientFactory
{
    private ApiClient apiClient;


    publi ApiClient GetApiClient()
    {
        try
        {
            String apiURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_URL"];
            apiClient = new ApiClient(apiURL);

            // Auth to the API to get our JWT token for subsequent requests.
            AuthResponse response = apiClient.Authenticate(new AuthRequest()
            {
                Type = UserType.Staff,
                Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_UserName"],
                Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Password"]
            });

            if (response != null)
            {
                //save the token for all subsequent requests
                apiClient.JwtToken = response.Token;
                response = null;
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("APIClient Could not authenticate.");
            }

            return apiClient;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        ApiClientFactory clientFactory = new ApiClientFactory();
        apiClient = clientFactory.GetApiClient();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    // use apiClient to call api method 

}
```

how to unit test GetApiClient of class ApiClientFactory.

Comment: There is not much logic to unit test in your method. If you still want to test it then you need to understand about Dependency Injection.

Comment: What exactly do you actually want to test?

Comment: @Hung Cao: please provide me some detail about to design this using  Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Since the factory instantiates an `ApiClient` directly, there's no way you can replace the `ApiClient` with a mock, so you can't test the factory without actually issuing a request to the server. Your factory shouldn't perform authentication, it should just create the object and return it.

Comment: I have created authentication in factory to do abstraction. Could please suggest testable implementation for it. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: @MitulRakholiya, the role of a factory is to create an object. If it does something else with the object it creates, the test code has no control over it, so it's not testable. I don't see any way to make your factory testable if it also does authentication (unless it delegates the object creation to a *real* factory that does nothing else... but then your original "factory" would no longer be a factory at all, since it would no longer be in charge of creating the object).

Answer (score 1):

If you move the usages of the APIClient into separate methods, particularly the `Authenticate` call, and mark those methods as virtual, you could mock the extracted methods in order to test the remainder of the factory logic. Something like this:

```
public ApiClient GetApiClient()
{
    try
    {
        String apiURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_URL"];
        apiClient = new ApiClient(apiURL);

        // Auth to the API to get our JWT token for subsequent requests.
        var request = new AuthRequest()
        {
            Type = UserType.Staff,
            Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_UserName"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Password"]
        });
        AuthResponse response = Authenticate(apiClient, request);

        if (response != null)
        {
            //save the token for all subsequent requests
            apiClient.JwtToken = response.Token;
            response = null;
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("APIClient Could not authenticate.");
        }

        return apiClient;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

internal virtual AuthResponse Authenticate(ApiClient apiClient, AuthRequest request)
{
    return apiClient.Authenticate(request);
}
```

Then, in your test, you do something like this:

```
public void MyTest() 
{
    var factoryMock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<ApiClientFactory>();
    factoryMock.Expect(x => x.Authenticate(...).Return(...);

    var client  = factoryMock.GetApiClient();

    Assert.That(client.xxx, Is.EqualTo(...));
}
```

Obviously, filling in whatever verification and expectations you want to use to validate your logic.